# How to fill session array with data from database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

I know this question might be very basic for someone experienced. But I'm still in the learning process so I need some help.

I want to populate a session array with data that's coming from the database. There can be multiple items in the session array. I'm trying to do it like this -

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `purchase_info_details` WHERE  `purchase_details_id` = '$pur_det_id'");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

   $data[$i]['purchase_details_id'] = $row['purchase_details_id'];
   $data[$i]['cid'] = $row['id'];
   $data[$i]['item_id'] = $row['item_id'];
   $data[$i]['unit_id'] = $row['unit_id'];
   $data[$i]['quantity'] = $row['quantity'];
   $data[$i]['price'] = $row['price'];
   $data[$i]['conv_rate'] = $row['conv_rate'];

   $_SESSION['list1_data']['purchase_details_id'] = $data[$i];
 }
```

FYI: purchase_details_id is the primary key. This code works partially. What I mean is I only get one row from the table in my session array but I need to get all the rows from the table that matches my SQL query.

I've been searching for a relevant example on the internet but yet to find any. I'm really stuck with it and couldn't find any solution. Please help!

Thanks!!

Comment: use another level in session array, like `$_SESSION['list1_data'][] = $data[$i];`

Comment: I believe you need to do session_start(); at the top of your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your are always overwriting the same data in your session array. When your loop is finished, you will have the last row from your dataset in your session array.

To add a new row in your session array everytime you can proceed with either:

```
$_SESSION['list1_data'][] = $data[$i];
```

or if you want a specific key from your data (assuming it is unique):

```
$_SESSION['list1_data'][$row['purchase_details_id']] = $data[$i];
```

Comment: finally, an answer that explains the solution and not just "do this" =)

Comment: Thanks!! @st2rw2od

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$_SESSION['list1_data'][$row['purchase_details_id']] = $data[$i];
```

This way you can directly access specific details id from the session. For example:

```
$row = $_SESSION['list1_data'][1]; //row for the id = 1
```

Pro tip: Always check if the key is set or else you will get warnings =)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

   $data[$i]['purchase_details_id'] = $row['purchase_details_id'];
   $data[$i]['cid'] = $row['id'];
   $data[$i]['item_id'] = $row['item_id'];
   $data[$i]['unit_id'] = $row['unit_id'];
   $data[$i]['quantity'] = $row['quantity'];
   $data[$i]['price'] = $row['price'];
   $data[$i]['conv_rate'] = $row['conv_rate'];

   $_SESSION["db_data"][$i] = $data[$i];// or just $_SESSION[$i] = $data[$i]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['list1_data']['purchase_details_id'] = $data[$i]; always overwrite and you get only last value . use $_SESSION['list1_data'][$row['purchase_details_id']] = $data[$i];
```

just assign array to session when you finish your loop . like below

```
 $_SESSION['list1_data'] = $data;

 or as you say product_id is unique then why you use $i ? (use $data[$row['purchase_details_id']]['purchase_details_id'] = value , use $data[$row['purchase_details_id']]['cid'] = value etc ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that  you are initialize the session() method, and you can make a 2 or 3 dimensional array as you need to keep the database value as @B-and-P mention in his comments.

thanks